# Android play store possible to update free app with in app purchases

Tags: android, google-play, app-store

I'm releasing an app soon and I know once you open a listing for a free app, it can not be converted to a paid app.

My app is free, but i'm planning to add an optional donation feature in the future using the in app purchases api. I haven't put this in my app yet, so once I make my listing for a free app, can it be updated to allow in app purchases?

thanks